# How to exclude a symbolic link in rsnapshot

Tags: backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I am using `rsnapshot` to manage my backups. The file `/home/foo/bar` is a symbolic link to a folder, and I want to exclude it. The `--exclude` option does not work, because if the pattern ends with a `/` then it will only match a directory, not a symlink.

How could I do?

Comment: do you want to exclude the symlink or the folder structure behind the symlink?

Comment: I wrote a better explanation here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371461/how-to-exclude-symbolic-link-in-rsync-rsnapshot/372151#372151